# Load user profile when app starts, crash when view is selected, convert PFFile to UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform

I am creating a custom profile for my users in an app. I have the profile picture stored as a PFFile with key `"profilePicture"` in my `User` data table. I want the UIImageView on the screen to be the users profile image from the the table I created.

Here is my code. I figured I could do this in my `viewDidLoad` function.

```
@IBOutlet var profPic: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"User")

    query.includeKey("profilePicture")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
    {
        (objects:[AnyObject]! , error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
            self.profPic = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("profilePicture") as UIImageView
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to do this? I get the common xcode error when I click to that view where it takes you to xcode and shows you the thread / stack errors. What I am asking seems fairly simple I feel like I am having a problem querying.

------------ Edit1----------

This is what I came up with from further playing with it still same result.

```
    var profile:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Users")
    profile.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
        {
            (objects:[AnyObject]! , error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
               let profPic = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("profilePicture") as UIImageView
            }
    }
```

------------ Edit2 ----------

```
    @IBOutlet var profPic: UIImageView!


    var query = PFQuery(className:"Users")
    query.whereKeyExists("profilePicture")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            let image: UIImage = objects["profilePicture"] as PFFile
            self.profPic.image = image

        }
        else {
            println("User has not profile picture")
        }
    }
```

Error is PFFile is not convertible to UIImage, should I be using PFImage? I am cant work around this some how. Thanks.

Here are some screen shots of whats happening.

[image]

Comment: You need to add the error text to the question. There are two reasons. First, it allows the text to be indexed by Stack Overflow and search engines. Second, it allows people with worn out eyes (like me) to read it.

Comment: 0x10559d662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax) is all it says. it doesnt show the error text except what I showed you in the screen shot @jww

Comment: I'm pretty sure PFUser doesn't have object of type `UIImageView` stored in the "profilePicture". What happens if you log what `PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("profilePicture")` returns?

Plus, to display an image in your imageView, you will not do it like that. You will do `self.profPic.image = someImage` given that someImage is a `UIImage`

Comment: @cjwirth could you provide a answer with some sample code, I think I understand what you mean I just cant wrap my head around, thank you.

Comment: @kareem - unfortunately, I cannot read the screen shot. So I can't see the error message, I can't the stack trace, I can't see the symbols surrounding the offending instructions, and I can't see the preceding instructions. Plus, Stack Overflow and search engines cannot index those things because they are tucked away in a screen capture.

Comment: @kareem Sure... https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f1320fb3241063be26a1 I'm pretty sure that you won't be getting a UIImageView from that line of code, I'm guessing that has a big part to do with it failing.

Comment: @cjwirth you are absolutely correct, I realized this now thank you, I am just stuck on converting a PFFile to a UIImage or getting access to the PFFile .image property

Comment: @kareem So does `PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("profilePicture")` return a `PFFile`?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @cjwirth, for some reason the answer was deleted, in order for my code to work this was what needed to be done. This shows the current users profile picture where I placed the imageview in the view.

```
@IBOutlet var profPic: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var query = PFQuery(className:"Users")
    query.whereKeyExists("profilePicture")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let imageFile = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile {
            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    self.profPic.image = UIImage(data: data)

        }
        else {
            println("User has not profile picture")
        }
    }

 }
```